# Code First Migrations MySQL - Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, code-first, migrations

Estou criando uma aplicação Web em C# e por questão do servidor de hospedagem, o banco é em MySql. Então eu instalei o MySql.Data.Entity, o EF6, ativei o Migrations, adicionei as class Migrations, mas na hora de dar o `Update-database -Verbose` retorna a mensagem:

> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.

Como já possuo o EasyPHP instalado, estou usando o MySql que já vem nele!

Contexto:

```
public DBContexto() : base("Contexto") { }
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();
    }
```

Conection String:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Contexto" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1:3306;Database=dbyou;Id=root;Password=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa é uma mensagem padrão informando que ao adicionar a flag Verbose você verá quais queries SQL estão sendo executadas na migration aplicada, se você recebeu apenas essa mensagem pode ficar tranquilo, pois não significa que aconteceu algum erro.

**Adicione a anotação em cima da classe do contexto**:

```
 [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
 public class SeuContexto{

    public SeuContexto()
        : base(/*AQUI DEVE ESTAR O NOME DA CONEXÃO DO CONNECTION STRING*/)
    {        
    }
```

Verifique se no web.config ou app.config tem sua connection string do MySQL, caso não tenha adicione-a e referencie-a na base do contexto.

Pode ser que o motivo de não estar salvando esteja aqui:

```
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

Pois ele está usando a connectionFactory do LocalDB, **altere para**:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, 
    MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, 
    EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Segue o link de um problema parecido com o seu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277677/dynamic-mysql-database-connection-for-entity-framework-6

Comment: O Problema é que ele não esta criando as Tabelas no  Banco! e quando eu  tento fazer via Data Model, não aparece o conector do SQL, apesar de eu ter instalado ele

Comment: voce utilizou o comando "add-migration XX"? Aonde XX é um nome de sua escolha para enumerar a migration

Comment: Fiz sim. Mais ele não cria as tabelas!

Comment: confira na sua app.config ou web.config a connection string do banco de dados, pode ser que esteja salvando no banco de dados padrão do projeto, vá em View>Sql object viewer (nao lembro o nome exatamente), fazendo isso abrirá um campo na esquerda do visual studio, verifique os bancos de dados ali presentes e se foi criado algum

Comment: A Connection String esta direcionando para o meu banco MySql: localhost:3306. dai no meu server, eu fui  criar uma conexão do MySql, porém só aparece do SQL Server e Oracle. Não aparece do MySql, porém eu  instalei o Conector NET

Comment: Verifique no contrutor da classe de contexto do entity framework, lá está escrito qual conexão ele está usando (herdando), como ao executar o update-database ele não apresenta nenhum erro a tabela está sendo criada, você só tem que descobrir aonde

Comment: Eu estou usando o Contexto e a Conection string criada! eu só não sei aonde esta sendo criada então! na SQL mostrada na verbosa, ele usa dbo.Pessoa, então esta usando o SQLServer? se sim, como poderia se estou direcionando o MySQL na ConnectionString

Comment: Por favor complemente sua pergunta com um trecho do código do contexto, obrigado

Comment: Eu fiz um teste. Adicionei um arquivo, depois o busquei e funcionou! Ou seja, ele esta criando uma tabela!

Comment: Vá na opção View>Server Explorer verifique todos os servidores, atualize as páginas, tem que estar em algum lugar ali, ou pode estar em algum db local, verifique as pastas do projeto por um arquivo .mdf

Comment: Acredito que mudando o XML conforme mudei a reposta vá fazer funcionar certo dessa, vez, caso minha reposta resolva seu problema por favor marque-a como a solução, obrigado